# Error trying to install Python on some friend's computer

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error, activepython

First time I got this error trying to install Python on some friend's computer (Windows7 - x64)

It says

```
C:\Users\Username\Desktop\proyect> myproyect.py  
    File "myproyect.py" line 1  
      ActivePython 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec 5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32  
                     ▲  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing here. You say you are trying to install Python, but what you are doing is running a file called "myproyect.py": why do you think that will install Python? And even though that has a .py extension, the contents of the file appear to not be in Python, but begin with  the text "ActivePython..."; what exactly is that file supposed to be?

Comment: I just re-installed Python a lot of times and this is what happend when I try to run a simple "hello world" program

Comment: Please copy the content of `myproject.py` here with an [edit]

Comment: But that file does appear to be a simple hello world, it appears to contain the text "ActivePython 2.7.11. etc". Maybe you should show the content of the file?

Comment: and I also see a `32 bit (Intel) on win32` in error message, and you are trying to install it on 64 bit?

Comment: It would appear your mistakenly ran `python > myproject.py` at some point and that would write that text to the top of the file.

Comment: hey thanks dude, I was trying to run a file with python data inside, big hug to you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file contains more than just python code, hence the syntax error.

Please check that file simply contains

```
print "hello world"
```

And not

```
ActivePython 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec 5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
# some other stuff... 
print "hello world"
```

Comment: yep, that was exactly what was happening